# how to get the user id from bearer token in header authorization

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

i have an async function that takes a bearer token sent from headers.authorization and returns the current connected user information.

```
exports.me = async (req, res) => {
  const accessToken = req.headers.authorization;

  const bearer = accessToken.split(" ");
  const bearerToken = bearer[1];
  req.token = bearerToken;
  // header take

  jwt.verify(bearerToken, process.env.SECRET_KEY, function (err, decoded) {
    if (decoded) {
      const now = new Date();
      User.findOne({ _id: decoded.id })
        .select("firstName  lastName email avatar birthday _id") 
        .then((user) => {
          return res.status(200).json(user);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          return res.status(404).json(err);
        });
    }
  });
};
```

instead of requesting **req.params.userId** from the front in the next function, i want to get the userId directly from the '**me()**' function

```
exports.getEvents = async (req, res) => {

  const allEvents = await Events.find({ owner: req.params.userId })
    .then((events) => {
      return res.status(200).json(events);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      return res.status(404).json(err);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue fixed by setting the id in the req.body and passing the me function as a middleware

```
User.findOne({ _id: decoded.id })
          .select("firstName  lastName email avatar birthday _id") 
          .then((user) => {
            req.body.userId = user._id
            next();
        })
```